# Observable is unicast by definition, but why it seem multicast with asynchronous creation operators such as interval and delay?

Tags: rx-java

Observable is unicast by definition, compared to Subject, and most creation operators, such as create just, but why it seem multicast with asynchronous creation operators such as interval and delay ?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boTta.png)

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNx2H.png)

Comment: sorry，first time to ask ，i dont understand and fix the code format mistake

Comment: Please don't post images of code and/or logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not multicast. It is still unicast. So why do you get output from ob1 and ob2 ?

Because the observable you create is a [cold observable.](https://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CHot%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9CCold%E2%80%9D%20Observables) You will get a fresh new stream every time you subscribe to it.

Let's analyze your log.
[image]

You see. The **ob1** receives the item of the stream first. And after 1500 milliseconds(The delay time your ob2 subscribes to the Observable.).The **ob2** receives the item from a new stream(another subscribe operate, another stream).

Then let's make your code really multicast and see what is different. Note the **publish()** operator.

```
        Observable ob1 = Observable
                .just(500, 400)
                .delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .publish().autoConnect();//publish operator make the observable hot and multicast!
        ob1.subscribe(i -> System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + " ob1: " + i));

        Observable.just(1).delay(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribe(i -> {
                    System.out.println("delay once");
                    ob1.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + " ob2: " + aLong));
                });

        Observable.just(1).delay(6000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribe(i -> {
                    System.out.println("delay after the observable finish it's stream.");
                    ob1.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + " ob3: " + aLong), Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> {
                        System.out.println("ob3 get completed!");
                    });
                });
```

[image]

Let's analyze the output.

First the **ob1** and **ob2** receives the item from the stream simultaneously.

Second, the **ob3** did not receive any item and get complete signore from the stream.

This time, your observable is truly multicasting.

Comment: thanks ~, its a vivid and detailed answer! +1